# BIRT Report: I want to modify the report based on the modified query. But I am not able to add Output columns in the dataset

Tags: report, birt

I have modifed the query to add 3 additional columns to the existing report. The query is set. But how to add the Output columns based on query in the dataset.Refer the below image links
[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OzNi.png)
[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP30y.png)

I am trying to add columns for data set. I cant find the add button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to he "Binding" register of the table/list item, then hit the "Refresh" button